# File redirection not working when using fork()

Tags: c, fork, io-redirection

I am trying to redirect the output of a command to a file. I've tried this as a standalone thing in main and I had no problem. The output was directed as intended. However, once I throw it into a fork the output is put into stdout rather than the file I am redirecting to. Admittedly I only learnt to use fork() very recently and am not aware of all of the considerations one needs to make when using it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *command[] = {"echo", "x", NULL};
    //int command_len = 4;

    //int file_in;
    int file_out;

    pid_t pid;


    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        // Forking unsuccessful
        printf("Error: fork unsuccesful\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Child process running\n");
        // Forking succesful
        file_out = open("test.out", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);

        dup2(file_out, 0);

        close(file_out);

        execvp(command[0], command);
        
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("child process completed\n");
    }



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any assistance anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "*I've tried this as a standalone thing in main and I had no problem*". Are you sure? Don't see how that could work even without `fork`. `dup2(file_out, 0)` is redirecting STDIN not STDOUT. Use `STDOUT_FILENO` instead (which is 1 not 0).

Comment: @kaylum you are right. my bad

Answer (score 1):

Mistakes abound.

```
        file_out = open("test.out", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
```

So far, so good. But the next line isn't what's expected. Should be:

```
        if (file_out == -1) {
             // Do something to report error here. Note that you can't call perror because you're in the fork child.
             _exit(1);
        }
```

```
        dup2(file_out, 0);
```

That's standard input. You want.

```
        dup2(file_out, 1);
```

```
        execvp(command[0], command);
    }
```

Noooooo.

```
        execvp(command[0], command);
        // Do something to report error here.
        _exit(-1);
    }
```

The simplest stupidest way to report error is something like this:

```
void perror_write(const char *source)
{
    // We cannot call malloc() because we're in a fork child.
    // mmap() is just too hard at this stage. It's slow. Live with it.
    char buf[80];
    int error = errno;
    write_error_msg(source);
    write_error_msg(": ");
    write_error_msg(strerror_r(error, buf, sizeof(buf)));
    write_error_msg("\n");
}

void write_error_msg(const char *msg)
{
    size_t len = strlen(msg);
    while (len > 0) {
        ssize_t offset = write(2, msg, len);
        if (offset <= 0) return;
        msg += offset;
        len -= offset;
    }
}
```